# Cannot Get JTable Total Width

Tags: java, swing, jtable, width

I am trying to set the column widths of my `JTable` with `timeLineDialog` as a percent of the total. I am being stopped because the `getWidth()` returning **0**.

```
dialog.add(header,BorderLayout.NORTH);
dialog.add(timeLineDialog,BorderLayout.CENTER);
int panelSize=timeLineDialog.getWidth();
System.out.println("total width="+Integer.toString(panelSize));
for (int i=0; i<percentWidths.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("setting column "+Integer.toString(i)+" to "+Integer.toString((int) Math.round(panelSize*percentWidths[i])));
    timeLineDialog.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth((int) Math.round(panelSize*percentWidths[i]));
}
timeLineDialog.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
dialog.add(footer,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

The debug output shows `panelSize=0`. How do I get the width of my `JTable`? TIA.

Comment: You're calling the method **before** you've rendered the GUI, and so it is returning an accurate value for the JTable *at that time*. If you need the size, do so after rendering, after calling `pack()`

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Comment: By default dialog height and width will be 0, we need to set the value explicitly or call pack() after adding components to the dialog it will size dialog based on the components.